# Casting: System.Attribute retrieved from Objecttypes

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, casting

I've written (using a sneak peek on the net) my generic method to get attributes on classnames. Here is the code.

**The attribute:**

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class FileType : Attribute
{
    public String TypeName { get; set; }
}
```

**The implementation**

```
[FileType (TypeName ="wordFile")]
public class BudFile
{ ... }
```

**My Generic Method**

```
    public T GetAttributeOfObject<T>(Type objectTypeToCheck)
    {
        object myAttribute = (T)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(objectTypeToCheck, typeof(T));
    }
```

**The Usage:**

```
BudFile A;
FileType myFileType = GetAttributeOfObject<FileType>(typeof(A));
```

**The Problem:**

I'm getting the error `Cannot convert type System.Attribute to T` on the following line:

```
        object myAttribute = (T)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(objectTypeToCheck, typeof(T));
```

Which makes sense since `Attribute.GetCustomAttribute` returns an object of `System.Attribute`. How can I **Safely** cast the retrieved `System.Attribute` to my attribute?

Comment: In .NET 4.5 you can use this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.customattributeextensions.getcustomattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx Is it .NET 4 or lower?

Comment: @Dennis its an older application (.net 4.0). Thank you for the page though. Interesting reading material!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need a constraint for `T` as `Attribute`. You get the compiler error because `T` could be anything which can't be casted to an `Attribute` type.

```
public T GetAttributeOfObject<T>(Type objectTypeToCheck) where T: Attribute
{
    return (T)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(objectTypeToCheck, typeof(T));
}
```